# PT100 v PT1000 - which to use

Tags: rtd

Under what circumstances is one better than the other? I can't seem to find much data on their use, as opposed to their resistances.

Comment: I heard the lower ohm ones react faster. And of course there is more current going through them.

Comment: A lot of stuff on the web.. how about a link or two, to what you've looked at.  (different R's may work better for different temperature ranges.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pt100 has lower resistance and probably is better for industrial situations with EMI.  The leadwire resistance is more of a factor and 3-wire connection is usually used (4-wire for lab type applications, it's rare in industry). Leakage due to moisture etc. is also less likely to affect the reading substantially. **It's also the most common standard** (which came about in part because of my 3rd point, since reasonably accurate thin-film RTDs are a relatively recent development).

Pt1000 can be used 2-wire in many cases because reasonable leadwires are relatively low resistance.

It's pretty impractical to make a wound-wire RTD of 1000 ohms so they are generally of thin-film construction, with all that implies. If it could be made it would be even more bulky, slow and fragile than a 100 ohm wound RTD.

Self heating is proportional to the output in either case, so it's a wash, but you need less current for the same output with a Pt1000 (perhaps a factor in loop-powered instrumentation).